I'm trying to remember a novel about an asteroid threatening to destroy the earth. I remember seeing the phrase "SHIVA IS COMING" on the cover
I'm trying to remember a novel about an asteroid threatening to destroy the earth. I remember seeing the phrase "SHIVA IS COMING" on the cover.
That may have been the title, or it may just have been the subtitle.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Could it be Shiva Descending? See the last line of the description:

From the far reaches of space an immense ball of orange flame hurtles toward a doomed planet. Terror sweeps the earth. City after city disappears in flaming craters or under tidal waves. World leaders are assassinated. There are mass suicides and mass orgies. There is nowhere to hide. There is nothing to do but wait. While doom cults dance naked in the streets, and the President of the United States lies with his mistress in the White House, drunk on pills and pleasure, astronauts Lisa Bander and Diego Calderon are in a riveting race against disaster. Leading two teams of international astronauts, they launch a desperate, off-planet mission against Shiva, knowing that failure to divert the massive asteroid will plunge an entire civilization -- and their own love-locked destinies -- into eternal, cataclysmic oblivion. The countdown has started. Shiva is Coming.



It could also be The Shiva Encounter. According to a review:

Cook repeats this line near the start of most chapters: ‘Shiva is coming….’ People debate the pros and cons of striking the asteroid that may or may not strike the Earth. The author thoroughly covers the issue of debris and invents a clever scheme to handle it.


